# Can I extend an Objective-C Foundation class so that it only affects my instances?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to make a class that returns an `NSDate`. It should be a "normal" `NSDate` that the user of my class can just use like `NSDate *meetingDate = [meeting getDate];`. But when the user does `meetingDate.description`, which is a normal property/method of an `NSDate`, I want my method to be called to get a custom format. If they create an `NSDate` on their own, I don't want the behavior of `.description` to be altered.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you wish to provide a custom `description` method? `description` should only be used for debugging purposes. The output should never be used to display values to a user or to persist or transfer an `NSDate` value.

Comment: Why is this question not equivalent to "Can I subclass `NSDate`"? (And the answer to that is you can provided you followed the rules in the [`NSDate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/). )

Answer (score 5):

Although `NSDate` is a class cluster, as others have pointed out, [Apple actually documents exactly what you need to do when you want to create your own subclass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) (see the *Subclassing Notes*). Here's a working version that overrides the description methods:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyDate : NSDate
@end


@implementation MyDate
{
    NSDate * _internalDate;
}

+ (instancetype)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)ti
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:ti];
}

- (instancetype)initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)ti
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    _internalDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:ti];

    return self;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
{
    return _internalDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
}

- (NSString *)descriptionWithLocale:(id)locale
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.timeIntervalSince1970];
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.timeIntervalSince1970];
}

@end
```

It seems that's all you need to do. Even though Apple wrote that we must implement the `NSCopying` methods, `copy` does seem to work just fine with `MyDate` as-is. Haven't tried `NSCoding`.

Note that you need to override both `description` and `descriptionWithLocale:` since the `%@` format specifier is documented to work like this:

> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by `descriptionWithLocale:` if available, or `description` otherwise.

… and there is a `-[NSDate descriptionWithLocale:]`, which get's preferred.

Test:

```
NSDate *test = [MyDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1000];
NSDate *test2 = [test copy];
NSLog(@"%@", test2); // Prints: 1000.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do *exactly* as you described, as you cannot have 2 versions of the same selector `-description` on the `NSDate` class at the same time.

however, you can use an Objective-C category to implement a `-customDescription` method for the `NSDate` class that is only visible to you and callable by you.

Comment: Can you think of some way to make a wrapper so that the calling code doesn't have to be changed to call `customDescription`? I can't modify the SDK that I need to hand this object over to.